# What is the percentage format string to always display the sign?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to display 0.12345 as "+12.3%".  Format string "P1" or "p1" gives "12.3%".  I have tried both "+P1" and "+p1" to no avail.

```
string sFoo = 0.12345.ToString("P1");
```

**Update**

I should have emphasized that I always want the proper sign, not "+".  If the number is -0.12345, "P1" works exactly as I want: "-12.3%".

Comment: Do you always want +. if thats the case then you can try out this `$"+{0.12345.ToString("P1")}"`

Comment: That won't work if the number is negative

Comment: No.  If the number is -0.12345, I do not want "+-12.3%".  I want "+" only if the number is positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite using `P1`, but same result:

```
0.12345.ToString("+#.#%;-#.#%");
```

If you prefer at least one leading digit (e.g. "+0.23%" instead of "+.23%"):

```
0.12345.ToString("+0.#%;-0.#%"));
```

Same for trailing digits (e.g. "+14.0%" instead of "+14%"):

```
0.12345.ToString("+0.0%;-0.0%"));
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--section-separator

Comment: Thank you.  This works exactly as I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var num = 0.12345;
    var sign = num > 0 ? "+" : ""; 
    var output = $"{sign}{num.ToString("P1")}";
```

Comment: Thank you.  This solves the problem, but I was asking specifically for a "format string".

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no format string to display the positive sign. I've searched in `NumberFormatInfo` if some custom format could accept this, but with no avail.

You can however build some extension methods to fit your needs :

```
public static string ToSignedPercent(this double input)
{
    return $"{(input >= 0 ? "+" : "")}{input.ToString("P1")}";
}

// ...

Console.WriteLine((0.12345).ToSignedPercent()); // +12.3%
Console.WriteLine((-0.6789).ToSignedPercent()); // -67.9%
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mM8F6R)

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your main method. basically this approaches just sets the variable sFoo to have format of percentage with two decimals.

```
        string sFoo = String.Format("Value: {0:P2}.", 0.12345); // formats as 12.35% 
        Console.WriteLine(sFoo);
```